# how to add subsite library to a webpart page at the rootsite

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server

In the code below I am adding a document library to a webpart which exist in the root site. When I try to add a library that exist in the subsite, the code throws an error saying that it cannot find the library.

Is it possible to add library that exist in a subsite to a web part that exist in the root site?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

        SPLimitedWebPartManager webparts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(web.Url + "/Pages/Engineering.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        //create new webpart object            
        ListViewWebPart wpNew = new ListViewWebPart();
        SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Testing");

            //set properties of new webpart object     
        wpNew.ListName = myList.ID.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();

        //set properties of new webpart object     
        wpNew.ZoneID = "Header";
        wpNew.Title = "Web Part Title";
        wpNew.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal;
        wpNew.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;

        ////add new webpart object to webparts collection     
        webparts.AddWebPart(wpNew, "Header", 0);

        //update spWeb object     
        web.Update();
        //manager.SaveChanges(wp);
    }
}
```

Edit 1

```
        SPWebCollection subsites = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();

        //create new webpart object            
        ListViewWebPart wpNew = new ListViewWebPart();
        //ContentByQueryWebPart wpNew = new ContentByQueryWebPart(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < subsites.Count; i++)
        {
            using (SPWeb subSiteWeb = subsites[i])
            {
                SPList CurrentList = subSiteWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                if (CurrentList != null)
                {
                    wpNew.ListName = CurrentList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                    //wpNew.ListUrl = CurrentList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
                    //wpNew.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    wpNew.Title = "Web Part Title";
                    wpNew.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal;
                    wpNew.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;

                    AddWebPartToPage(web, "Pages/" + pageName, "Header", 0, wpNew);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You have to define the subweb location, otherwise it's only looking at the same site level as your code.

Comment: yes, I have done that in using the code in Edit 1, but it says that list does not exist. The list is there actually and I can see it when I debug the code.

Comment: I'll add an answer with a little more detail

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a static URL, then you could define the subsite in your original code by changing the line

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
```

to something like this:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("http://siteURL/subsite"))
```

Otherwise, when you call ***web.Lists.TryGetList("Testing");*** later on, it's looking for the list in the root of the site collection.

Comment: if you look at my code above you will see that I use TryGetList(), but still it does not work with ListViewWebPart.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure even TryGetList is still contextual. It searches for the list dynamically by name, but only within the defined web. Hopefully someone with a little more dev experience can confirm or not - I've never used TryGetList myself.